# Footer with sum in one2many_list odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How define gray footer under one2many_list for sum, eg. 
https://postimg.org/image/jc9alzoeh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in the embedded tree of your One2many field add sum="Title":

```xml
    <field name="o2m_field_name" >
        <tree>
            ...
            <field name="field_name" sum="Total field name"/>
        </tree>
        <form>
        ....
        ...
        </form>
    </field
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `sum` attribute to the `duration field`.
An example with `invoice lines`:

```
<field name="invoice_line" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list" context="{'type': type}">
<tree string="Invoice Lines" editable="bottom">
    <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
    <field name="product_id" on_change="product_id_change(product_id, uos_id, quantity, name, parent.type, parent.partner_id, parent.fiscal_position, price_unit, parent.currency_id, parent.company_id, context)"/>
    <field name="name"/>
    <field name="company_id" invisible="1"/>
    <field name="account_id" groups="account.group_account_user" domain="[('company_id', '=', parent.company_id), ('journal_id', '=', parent.journal_id), ('type', '=', 'other')]" on_change="onchange_account_id(product_id, parent.partner_id, parent.type, parent.fiscal_position,account_id)"/>
    <field name="account_analytic_id" groups="analytic.group_analytic_accounting" domain="[('type','!=','view'), ('company_id', '=', parent.company_id), ('state','not in',('close','cancelled'))]"/>
    <field name="quantity"/>
    <field name="uos_id" groups="product.group_uom" on_change="uos_id_change(product_id, uos_id, quantity, name, parent.type, parent.partner_id, parent.fiscal_position, price_unit, parent.currency_id, parent.company_id, context)"/>
    <field name="price_unit"/>
    <field name="discount" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line"/>
    <field name="invoice_line_tax_id" widget="many2many_tags" context="{'type':parent.type}" domain="[('parent_id','=',False),('company_id', '=', parent.company_id)]"/>
    <field name="price_subtotal" sum='Total'/>
</tree>
```

It should looks like:

```
<field name="field name" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list">
    <tree editable="bottom">
        ...
        <field name="duration" sum='Total'/>
    </tree>
</field>
```